# Coded UI: What is the best way to write a method which has multiple optional parameters of same data type

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am writing a method in Coded UI which accepts multiple optional input parameters of the same type. My question is what is the best practice of writing such a method. should it be using method overloading (which is suggested in many places on the internet) or named argruements and optional parameters combination.
The method is actually trying to enter values in the below fields :

Name: string: Required
Age: string: Required
Location: string: Optional
Checkbox to sign up: Optional
If Checkbox is checked: enter some more details in the fields below.

If I am using combination of named arguments and optional parameters then the list of parameters in the method definition looks long and I am not sure if its easy to read and with method overloading am not sure if I  pass/skip multiple optional parameters then it will solve the purpose.
I am new to C# coding so any pointers is much appreciated.

Comment: My suggestion is create a couple of classes to act as wrappers around the different types of information. You specifically mentioned every parameter has the same type - however I'm betting every parameter has a different purpose. Build your objects based on that. For instance if the `checkbox` is checked you may pass in a `NewAccount` object to hold that information. `Name`, `age`, and `location` could all be a part of a `Person` object. This simplifies your method signature and keeps your code more to the point.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I agree with you that creating classes as wrapper for same kind of fields and then passing the class object would be a neat way to do it. But how will my method know which parameter to put in which optional field . For ex: if I have 3 optional fields-email,gender,ordertype and I want to pass only email, ordertype, how can  my method understand this ?

Comment: if the wrapper object has a field for, lets say email, and that field is null (because you never set it because they didn't give it to you), then your method knows not to worry about it. The point is your objects are just containers for the values you need. if the value wasn't set then it's not there and you don't need to care about it -- unless it's a required variable, then you should throw an exception and tell the user that field is required.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Sorry if I am taking time to get this. But if my wrapper object doesnt pass the email field but gender and ordertype (because I set it) then what would be my method signature. The reason I ask this is all these gender, ordertype, email are of "string" type. My method will have unique  signature saying if its "email" then enter it in email field. So how would my method signature look like here so as to make sure it enters the right value in the right field.

Comment: the wrapper classes aren't passing anything -- they are what is being passed. they contain the values of the different parameters you want which you set when you call the class's constructor. if any of those class's fields are null, then you can ignore them. then all of your methods' signatures become one single signature which checks for nulls. I hope i'm not making this sound harder than it actually is.

Answer (score 1):

Use a wrapper object to contain your fields:

```
class Person{
    string name location;
    Gender gender;
    int age;
    public Person(string name, int age, string location = null, Gender gender = null){
        // set fields
        // location is optional so it might be null.
        // Gender can be an object or an enum type.
    }
}
class NewAccount{
    String email, password;
}
class Order{
    String OrderType = null;
}
```

then your method's signature would look something like:

```
public void myMethod(Person person, Order order, NewAccount newAccountInfo = null){
    //Do whatever here
}
```

The point is that these objects provide a well defined interface for your method to use instead of using a bunch of parameters that may or may not be there.

Comment: Thanks Richard for such a detailed and informative response. One more question I have is lets say in the code above if Person.gender is passed null then in myMethod do I have to define logic to say when gender!=null then enter gender in "Gender" field ?

Comment: Yes you need to check for null. Not because you need to get that info in myMethod but because you need to know in case you're going to store it or otherwise use it.

Comment: If your myMethod absolutely has to use the gender then it should be required. I don't have a complete story on what you're trying to do here - but regardless you should have all of the information you need, even if its optional (in which case it's null), before you try calling myMethod - you must have it regardless if its null or not before using it. If it is null and you try to use it you'll get an exception. if the value is null and its required in order to complete a given task then you have a problem and should throw an exception - that's validation.

Comment: Thank you so much for all this information. This is really helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. If i've answered your question then please feel free to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case method overloading is the best thing you can do. We used always overloading the method in our classes for this kind of problem. Remember the case that someone doesnt want to put in the Location but wants so sign up.

Comment: Thanks for your response so with method overloading I would have to create multiple methods with unique signatures. But only problem is there are multiple optional fields with same data(string) type (I havn't included above in my example), so in that case how will my method know which optional field to use ?

Comment: im not the best at c++ but i always try the simplest way to do something. i think it would look like this:
`
void person(string name,string age)
void person (string name ,string age , string location)
void person(string name, string age, string location, bool checkbox)
void person(string name, string age , bool checkbox)`

someone should correct me if im wrong but that is my way how i would do it.

Comment: Passing in a parameter object is probably better than overloading all the combinations.